# Can't add a Follow Path Constraint in Object Mode

Tags: animation, constraints, object-mode

For some reason I can't work out how to apply a Follow Path Constraint to my character in Object Mode. Something has gone a bit wrong in my outliner somewhere... The option to add a Bone Constraint appears in Pose Mode no problem, but selecting the rig in the hierarchy won't allow me to add a constraint. All the options are greyed out. I've tried selecting all my objects and grouping them, but that doesn't work either. I'm a bit stumped as to what to do.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: in Pose mode you will have the Bone Constraint available, and in Object mode you will have the Object Constraints available, and it works fine with your file

Comment: Odd. Can't get it to show for me. How have you done it? If I have my model's layer active, the armature layer, select the armature, I can select Pose Mode and have access to the Constraint property. If I select a part of the model and I'm in Object Mode, I don't have it. :-\

Comment: I'm such a fool. The option was there the whole time. >_< I got confused due to the button looking different from the Constraints option for bones. Though I am having problems getting my character to walk along a path.